# running nodejs app inside go

Tags: node.js, go

I have a requirement. Is there a way to run nodejs apps inside golang? I need to wrap the nodejs app inside a golang application and in the end to result a golang binary that starts the nodejs server and then to be able to call nodejs rest endpoints. I need to encapsulate in the golang binary the entire nodejs application with nodem_odules, if necessarily the nodejs runtime.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This sounds like an A/B problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a Go program that includes e.g. a zipped Node application that it extracts and starts but it will be very hard to do well - you will have huge binaries, delays in extracting files, potential portability problems etc. Usually when you want to call REST endpoints then you host your Node app on some server and you let the client app (the Go app in your example) to connect to that Node app to work correctly. Advantages are that it is much faster, the app is much smaller, you don't have portability issues with Node binaries and addons and you can quickly update your backend any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a very bad idea to embed a nodejs app into your golang, for various reasons such as: size, security updates pushing, etc.

However, if you so strong feel that they should be together, you could easily create a `docker` container with these two (a golang server + a node app) and launch them via docker. You can set the entrypoint to a `supervisord` daemon so that your node server as well as the golang server can be brought up when your container is run.

If you are planning to deploy via `kubernetes` you can create two individual docker containers (one for the golang server, one for the node server) but deploy them always together as a `pod` too.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple projects to embed binary files and/or file system data into your Go application.

Look at 'Alternatives' section of project 'vfsgen':

https://github.com/shurcooL/vfsgen#alternatives